# Uploading multiple photos returns OAuthException for some of them

Tags: facebook-graph-api, batch-file, facebook-batch-request

I'm uploading multiple photos to the user's application album using a Graph API Batch Request.

For some mysterious reason, I get a 400 Error code for some photos, but not for others, in the same batch.

See the result here : http://pastie.org/3635995

Doing the same batch, with the same photos, doesn't fail on the same photos.
Sometimes I have 1 erros, sometimes 10.

Any suggestions ?

Here is a dump of the batch I send : http://pastie.org/3636047

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen, it's just the nature of the Facebook API.  If your calls are mission critical, you will need to setup a "retry queue" of API calls that do fail.  Give them three chances to fail before you finally give up and log it as errorred.  Also, be sure to give a few seconds/minutes in between retry attempts.